# When I pass array in a react functional component, it turns to an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

Hi I have to pass array as props to a functional component.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const FBS = ({ figures }) => {
    console.log(typeof figures);
    return figures.map((item, key) => <p key={key}>{item.description}</p>);
  };
  const figures = [
    {
      config: 112,
      description: "description text 1"
    },
    {
      config: 787,
      description: "description text 2"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <FBS {...figures} /> */}
      <FBS figures={figures} />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id='root' />
</body>
```

But it is converted to an object in the child component.
Please look at the render function. When I pass array as {...figures} I don't get it as Array in the FBS component due to which I can't run map function on it. Whereas when I pass it as figures={figures}, I get an array.
I want to pass it as {...figures}.

Please help

Please look at my code for better understanding. [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jjymk12z73)

Comment: Maybe `{ [...figures] }`?

Comment: The codesandbox works perfectly for me.

Comment: As Vladimir said, the codesandbox work just fine.. Moreover, if you write `console.log(Array.isArray(figures));` it returns `true`

Comment: It works alright, but what OP is wanting is imo, the same behavior when `figures={figures}` is changed to just `{...figures}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to have additional object which will have pair of key and value which will be destructured as your `props` to the React Component.

```
const props = {
  figures, // shorter way of writing figures: figures
  // Any other objects you'd like to pass on as props
}
```

and then, you can do:

```
<FPS {...props} />
```

[**Updated Code**](https://codesandbox.io/s/7m3yxxp7wx)

Basically you can only destructure an object in the React Component because then the destructured object's key-value pairs will become `props` to the component.

For better understanding,

```
const arr = [{ a: 'a'}]
{...arr}
```

will give:

```
{
  0: {a: 'a'}
}
```

because `0` is the key as it is an array as opposed to an object, so what you were really doing was passing a prop with name `0` instead of `figures` and `figures` was `undefined` and hence the error.

Comment: So you are implying that we cannot destruct object into array of objects the way I want?

Comment: @Rickie No. If you did it that way, the first object would be under `this.props.0` and the second object would be under `this.props.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Figure from './Figure';
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const figures = [
    {
      config: 112,
      description: "description text 1"
    },
    {
      config: 787,
      description: "description text 2"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>

      { 
        figures.map((figure, key) => {
          return <Figure key={key} {...figure}/>
        })
      }

    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And create a component called Figure like this:

```
import React from "react";

const Figure = (props) => {
   return (
    <div>
     <p>{props.description}</p>
     <p>{props.config}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Figure;
```

Comment: I have to iterate through a lot of objects from that array. It's an array of objects. The child component is not for printing just a single value bro

Comment: You can pass as many value as you want like it:
I updated the child component
Thank you